# Reference error "x" is not defined. when running commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm doing my first discord bot from a github repository. It connects to discord, and logs into the server, but won't respond to `!help` commands etc.
It's not my code so I'm not super familiar with it, but the code for the commands seems to be fine

```
if (command.content === '!create' && !game) {
  createGame(command)
} else if (command.content === '!start' && game && !game.started) {
  command.delete()
  game.start()
} else if (command.content === '!help') {
  command.channel.send(`!create: Create a new game\n!start: Start the game previously created`)
}if (message.content === 'restartthebot') {
  if (message.author.id !== 'Owners ID') return;
  message.channel.send('Restarted.').then(() => {
  process.exit(1);
})
};
```

I get this error message in my terminal console

```
(node:2611) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: command is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Applications/werewolf-discord-master 2/src/index.js:63:3)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (/Applications/werewolf-discord-master 2/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:431:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (/Applications/werewolf-discord-master 2/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:415:10)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (/Applications/werewolf-discord-master 2/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:197:14)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at WebSocketShard.checkReady (/Applications/werewolf-discord-master 2/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:475:12)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/Applications/werewolf-discord-master 2/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:447:16)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/Applications/werewolf-discord-master 2/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/Applications/werewolf-discord-master 2/src/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2611) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2611) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

any help would be much appreciated as I'm on a bit of a time crunch here.

Comment: Your going to have to include a lot more detail on what are trying to do. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?.

Comment: We have no idea, because we have no way to reproduce the problem. And Java ≠ JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

instead of command.content make it message.content to make it work as you havent defined command and please please dont copy code.

```
if(message.content === "!help" ........
```